# ar x extracting error file format not recognized error

Tags: files, archive, extract

I got the error `file format not recognized` while executing this command: `ar x *******.deb` to extract the contents of a Debian package. How can I fix this?

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Please explain what happens, when you try to use the methods in the link (from my previous comment), and what you expect to happen instead. Do you want to install the program(s) from the debian package or do you only want to extract them 'as files' into some arbitrary directory? -- `sudo dpkg -i package.deb` should install `package` if that is what you want. `ar x package.deb` will simply extract the files `control.tar.gz`  `data.tar.xz`  `debian-binary` into the current directory. -- If something else is happening I think your deb file is corrupted.

Comment: The file is likely corrupted. Try downloading it again.